# How do I resolve this error in getting the selected string of a ListBox in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to get a string of a Listbox. This is my code:

```
db.Employees.Select(x => x.LastName).OrderBy(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
var selectedEmployee = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(selectedEmployee);
```

The error I got is `System.NullReferenceException`. Not sure why though.

So how do I fix this error? By the way, everything is in the `Window_Loaded` method.

Comment: In line 1, you fill the listbox. In line 2 you want the selected item. In between, there's just ~ 0 ms for the user to select something.

Comment: listBox1.SelectedItem is not set yet! so it throws NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

As @ElyasEsna said, you never set listBox1.SelectedItem, and that's why it throws NullReferenceException.

So I rewrote your code this way:

```
db.Employees.Select(x => x.LastName).OrderBy(x => x).ToList().ForEach(x => listBox1.Items.Add(x));
listBox1.SelectedItem = // list item that you will select, depending on the choice of your program
var selectedEmployee = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(selectedEmployee);
```